# Acessing Google Calendar api in android

Tags: android, rest, openssl, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I am new to use the Google API. I am trying to retrieve the Google calendar API and show the events data to users. I have gone through "http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-android-sample/instructions.html?r=default", But I am struck with API-key generation.

Could please tell me the how to generate the oauth2.0 key using openssl.

I am planning to consume the Google calendar API using **rest web services**, so could please help me how to consume the Google calendar API using rest web services instead of client libraries.

Thanks & Regards
mini.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Find out the location of your debug certificate.** Go to Eclipse: Window--> Preferences-->Android-->Build  The location of the file will be at the bottom in 'Default debug keystore' or 'Custom debug keystore'. Make a note of this.
2. **Find out the location of your Java JDK's bin folder.** In my case it is: 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin'. This depends on the JDK version you have.

   Open a command window there. (On Windows 7:  SHIFT+ right click on the folder then select 'Open command window here' from the context menu.)
3. **Get the SHA1 fingerprint from your keystore using the Keystore tool.** (See screenshot)

   ```
   keystore -list keystore 'path-to-your-keystore'
   ```

   (In my case it is: C:\Users\D\.android\debug.keystore)

   Enter the password for your keystore then make a note of the SHA1 certificate fingerprint. If you are using the default Android debug key then the password is: 'android.
4. **Register the app and the SH1 fingerprint on Google apis console** as per the instructions on that link you included. 'Create another client ID' --> Select 'Installed application' --> select 'Android' --> Enter package name for your app and the SHA1 fingerprint from the previous step --> 'Create client ID'
5. **Repeat steps 2-4 with your release certificate.**

That's it, the example app should work now. Good luck.

[image]